# can't change parent element properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two div elements, in the first one I put three buttons. here is the code

it works properly but the problem is in reset button (it should move all the buttons to start div) when I press it just moves 2 elements back to the starting div. what can be a problem?

```js
function move(element){
    let newParent = document.querySelector('#favourites');
    newParent.append(element);
  }

function reset(){
    let startingDiv = document.querySelector('#startingArea');  
    let favouritesDiv = document.querySelector("#favourites");

    var children = favouritesDiv.children;

    for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
        startingDiv.append(children[i]);
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Click on your favourite wrestler<h1>
    <div id="startingArea">
        <button onclick='move(this)' id="cena1">John Cena</button>
        <button onclick='move(this)' id="cena2">Jooohn Ceenna</button>
        <button onclick='move(this)' id="cena3">JOoOoOOoooOooOOooOohn CeeeeeeEEEnaaaaaaa</button>
    </div>
      <h3>Your Favourite Wrestlers</h3>
      <div id="favourites">
      </div>
      <br><br><br>
      <button onclick="reset()">reset</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: set the default schema of your starting div in a separate `global` variable than on the `reset` just make the property `innerHTML` of the `favourites` to blank and set the starting div to the global variable's value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code for the reset function and it should work:

```
function reset(){
    let startingDiv = document.querySelector('#startingArea');  
    let favouritesDiv = document.querySelector("#favourites");

    while(favouritesDiv.firstChild) {
        startingDiv.append(favouritesDiv.firstChild);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the HTMLCollection you get from the "children" property into a standard array and it works:

```
var starter = document.querySelector('#startingArea');  
var childrenCollection = document.querySelector("#favourites").children; 
var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(childrenCollection);

for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
    starter.append(children[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple way you can do this way.

```
function reset() {
            let startingDiv = document.querySelector('#startingArea');
            let favouritesDiv = document.querySelector("#favourites");
            startingDiv.innerHTML = favouritesDiv.innerHTML;
            favouritesDiv.innerHTML = "";
        }
```